# How to send file and json data with python requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to send a file with json data attached to that request to a server.
I'm specifying file as

```
my_file = open(filename, 'rb')
file = {
        'upload': (
            os.path.basename(filename), my_file ,
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        )
    }
```

and attaching some data like the following:

```
data = {
        'uuidKey': str(user_key),
        'agree-term': False,
        'is_tarh': is_incentive_traffic_zone,
        'description': ''
    }
```

finally I'm putting all this together using python requests library like this:

```
headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
result = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule-payment", files=file,
                        data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

setting Content-Type to application/json results in error. the question is, how can I send a file and some json like data to a server using python requests library like when you create a form and send them that way?

I've also tried to use json parameter in requests.post but that doesn't work as well

Comment: I'd mark this question as *"caused by typo"* as solution is just to remove unnecessary `json.dumps()` call. I don't think that it's a common problem as neither in official docs nor in somehow popular tutorials you won't find such a code, so the problem seems to be caused by chain of experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OlvinRoght I found the answer.

you can set data arguments to whatever data you have and files argument for files.

like this:

```
my_file = open(filename, 'rb')
file = {
        'upload': (
            os.path.basename(filename), my_file ,
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        )
    }
data = {
        'uuidKey': str(user_key),
        'agree-term': False,
        'is_tarh': is_incentive_traffic_zone,
        'description': ''
    }

result = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule-payment", data=data, files=file)
```